# Each and every row is showing but pagination not working in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-3

Building this pagination by seeing some tutorials and now got stuck with a very bad situation every thing seems right from my eye but i need some expert view to take a look at my code and guide me where i am doing the mistake. Every records from the database is showing pagination links were also working but when i click any of the pagination link then it will take me to the 404 not found page.

```
if (!function_exists('pagination_configuration')){
  function pagination_configuration($base_url, $total_rows, $per_page='50', $uri_segment='3', $num_links='4', $use_page_numbers=TRUE) {
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = $base_url;
    $config["total_rows"] = $total_rows;
    $config["per_page"] = $per_page;
    $config["uri_segment"] = $uri_segment;
    $config['num_links'] = $num_links;
    $config['use_page_numbers'] = $use_page_numbers;

    $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
    $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';

    //First Link
    $config['first_link'] = 'First';
    $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    //Last Link
    $config['last_link'] = 'Last';
    $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    //Next Link
    $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
    $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    //Previous Link
    $config['prev_link'] = 'Prev';
    $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';

    //Current link
    $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
    $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</li></a>';

    //Digits Link
    $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
    $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
    return $config;
 }
}
```

code in my controller name Cities

```
//Pagination starts
    $total_rows = $this->cities_model->record_count('pp_cities');
    $config = pagination_configuration(base_url("admin/cities"), $total_rows, 50, 3, 5, true);

    $this->pagination->initialize($config);
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(2)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
    $page_num = $page-1;
    $page_num = ($page_num<0)?'0':$page_num;
    $page = $page_num*$config["per_page"];
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
//Pagination ends
```

and my view page call is

```
<div class="paginationWrap"> <?php 
      echo ($result)?$links:'';?> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in your controller you should load this ..$this->load->helper("url");
        $this->load->model("Countries");
        $this->load->library("pagination");

Comment: Can you post the actual base url for this?

Comment: i think you read this articles. this article will help you.. https://www.formget.com/pagination-in-codeigniter/

Comment: @SaurabhParekh this is an on going client project and sorry to say that i don't have permission to  share url anywhere

Comment: @RohitPoonia. Ok not an issue. You may have to add index.php in your base url. Also check route file for this. You likely to be have an issue at these two locations.

Comment: @BilalAhmed I tried adding those but nothing works. also i am making this pagination from that tutorial only

Comment: @SaurabhParekh i tried adding index.php but that doesn't changed anything .. i will check the routes

Comment: remove if ( ! function_exists('pagination_configuration')){ ..... this condition and run the code..

Comment: check below link http://only4ututorials.blogspot.in/2014/04/pagination-with-codeigniter.html